# How Stop Team Build from Precompiling

Tags: asp.net, tfsbuild

I've got an ASP.NET website project in my Solution, in Visual Studio 2010.
I'm using TFS 2010 to build the Solution.  The website is getting
precompiled (no .cs files).  What / where do I make changes to stop the site
from getting precompiled during build?  I suppose it's using MSBUILD, and
I've already made manual tweaks the build project file to deploy site after
a build.  So I'm really hoping there's a switch somewhere that tells the
system not to precompile during a TFS build.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want it precompiled? What's the problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: Requirements defined they want unprecompiled website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had this problem. Though I wanted the automated build to **perform** the build, I didn't want that precompiled version shipped. I wanted the full source to be shipped. To accomplish this, when I modified my TFSBuild.proj file to transport the files I used the `Sources` folder instead of the `$(OutDir)` folder. This way the site still got precompiled into the `$(OutDir)` and would properly fail if there was a problem, but the version transported to the website itself would be the actual .vb and .cs files themselves.

*Note: The reason I want the source files for the website rather than the precompiled version is that the sites covered in my automated build frequently undergo changes to individual pieces and need to be immediately updateable as stand alone items. This is a requirement of the business more than a requirement of the technology.*